# Can we loop a query to update 1000 rows and then update next 1000 rows and so on

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I'm stuck at this point that I have more than 26.4 Millions rows to update. but MySql is taking too much time to update. Is there any way to update all rows in 1000 rows chunk automatically (loop)?

My code is given below:

```
UPDATE alpha a
JOIN price p ON a.shop_id = p.shop_id
AND YEAR(a.date) = p.year
AND MONTH(a.date) = p.month
AND HOUR(a.time) = p.hour
SET a.rate = p.rate
```

Comment: If you are using java, try JDBCtemplate batch update.

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27938958/update-mysql-table-in-chunks ?