# How can I finish my MySQL fetch after searching a specific amount of rows even if the row is not found?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL Database with over 100k rows, so I need to make a search to fetch only the last 1000 rows , so if it is not found in the last 1000 rows the fetch ends (even if it is not found)

Example: if my table is like that

```
id   name
1     AL
2     BL
...
1000  P12
1001  P15
```

And I do a fetch like this: `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE name = 'AL' ONLY LAST 1000 ROWS ORDER BY id DESC` (Since I don't know what to use I invented the ONLY LAST 1000 ROWS)

This should return empty because I wanted my query to get the information only if it was on the last 1000 rows, not on the 1001th as specified.

Using LIMIT field doesn't work as it would LIMIT the FOUND ROWS not when they are not found.

Is there a way to implement this in MySQL ? 
Thank you!

Comment: You need to use `OFFSET`

Comment: OFFSET needs the number of which row to start from, I need to get the last X rows without knowing in which row it is.

Comment: But you explicitly want the last 1000 rows so just start from row 99,000

Comment: The table is not EXACTLY 10000, I don't know how many rows there is in the table, it can have 250000 (in this case it would be 249000) or 315000 (in this case would be 314000 rows) so I can't specify the number of rows, as I don't know how many rows the table is currently in

Comment: So then simply count the amount of rows, then use that number ?

Comment: @Grego you can create store procedure for this you can follow this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27938958/update-mysql-table-in-chunks

Comment: Simple approach: Nest two selects while the inner includes the top 1000 rows and the outer selects what you need from the result of the inner.

Comment: @ProEvilz your approach is very inefficient and hardcoding row numbers into SQL queries is not a strong contender for futureproofing this query, as touched upon by Grego.

Answer (score 1):

As touched on in the comments, you can use `OFFSET` to get the `id` of the 1000th last record, then `SELECT` records with an `id` larger than that record's `id`.

Something like this:

```
SELECT name 
FROM myTable 
WHERE id > (SELECT id FROM myTable ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1000)
AND name = 'AL'
```